# Can I test my iPad app on someone else's iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios

I'm developing an iPad app, and want to test it on a friend's iPad.  Before I buy the $99 developer account, I just want to make sure that this will work.

Does my friend's device have to use my apple ID in order to install the provisioning profile?  Is there anything that would change about his iPad (besides the ability to install my app, of course)?

Thanks!

Comment: This is what ad-hoc distribution is all about :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the $99 developer package, you can install your app on up to 100 test devices, and they don't need to use your Apple ID.

All that changes on the iPad is that there's an additional section within settings that lists the provisioning profile(s) present on the device. However, you *might* want to get your friend to do a backup (via iTunes) before you borrow it, if only in case it falls off the edge of a table or something. :-)

Answer (score 3):

maybe this could help, http://testflightapp.com/  Free OTA installation...

Answer (score 1):

> Before I buy the $99 developer account, I just want to make sure that this will work

You don't have the developer account? If so, you won't be able to test apps on the device, no matter who that device belongs to

Comment: Yeah, I understand that much.  I just didn't want to invest in the developer account before I knew this would work.  I don't have an iPad of my own, so if this didn't work, I was going to scrap the project.